# Scatter plot won't show any points

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to print a scatter plot in Colab with data that has been pulled in okay. But I get

```
KeyError: 'Wavelength (nm)'
```

and a graph with no points on it

[image]

Comment: Please consider entering code rather than a screenshot of it, as it make it harder to write an answer.

Comment: Noted, thanks. I'm new to this so that's helpful going forward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work? (input your column names and plot kind instead of ...)

```
gaas.reset_index().plot(...)
```